# LARAVEL : Destroy and detach method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to delete a Poll with this function where I need to detach relations :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $poll = Poll::findOrFail($id);
    $poll->answers()->detach();
    $poll->poll_user()->detach();
    $poll->delete();
}
```

But I'm getting this error message, I don't know why :

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()

Here is the Poll model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Poll extends Model
{

    /**
     * La table utilisée par le modèle
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'polls';

    /**
     * On utilise les dates de mise à jour
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * Attributs autorisés en ensignement de masse.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['question'];

    /**
     * Relation de type 1:n
     *
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations
     */
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Answer');
    }

    /**
     * Relation de type n:n
     *
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is your poll/answers relationship? Can you post your Poll model?

Comment: oneToMany, 1-poll, n-answers

Comment: What version of Laravel? You sure you don't need to use ```dissociate()``` instead of ```detach()```?

Comment: `detach()` is for many to many relation.

Comment: I've tried also with dissociate, i get the same error : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::dissociate(), version is 5.2.6

Comment: Can you post your Poll model? Otherwise we just keep guessing.

Comment: Where does ```$poll->poll_user()``` come from? I don't see it in your model.

Comment: as it's a manyToMany relation i thought I had to delete the user in the association table but anyway I changed that into $poll->users()->detach it still doesn't work :/

Comment: So if poll/answers is one-to-many shouldn't you use ```$poll->answers()->dissociate();```?

Comment: Yeah i've tried that but it gives me the same error : BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2117:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::dissociate()

Comment: I'm out of suggestions. I will post my whole answer and see if it makes any sense. Otherwise, I would check that it is actually returning a Poll with ```findOrFail```

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * Removing an entity
 *
 * @param  integer $id
 * @return void
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->getById($id)->users()->detach();
    $this->getById($id)->answers()->delete();
    $this->getById($id)->delete();
}

/**
 * Getting an entity by id
 *
 * @param  integer $id
 * @return void
 */
public function getById($id)
{
    return Poll::find($id);
}
```

Comment: Could you translate these comments to english?

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know if it's correct or not but I've done the following and it works perfectly :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $poll = Poll::findOrFail($id);
    $poll->answers()->delete();

    $poll->users()->detach();
    $poll->delete();
}
```

Comment: maybe it's because an answer cannot have a poll set with null. but the error message is not explicit...

Comment: As long as it works. Others might have more insight.

Comment: This works because the Poll has a oneToMany relationship with the answers. Detach only works on manyToMany relationships like users()

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $poll = Poll::findOrFail($id);
    $poll->answers()->dissociate();
    $poll->users()->sync([]);
    $poll->delete();
}
```

If that doesn't work then might need to look at your other models or migrations.

Comment: I've got the same xD : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()

Comment: well, it works without detaching the relations, but I think that's not correct at all

Comment: sorry, had sync on 1-m by mistake

Comment: So it works? Probably because you have cascade on delete? Depends on your migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you set up connections in the right way in your models and I think you are trying to call this method in parent Controller (not in child Controller).
Based on these this code should work...

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $poll = Poll::findOrFail($id);

    foreach ($poll->answers as $answer) 
    {
        $answer->poll()->dissociate();
        $answer->save();
    }

    foreach ($poll->user as $user) 
    {
        $user->poll()->dissociate();
        $user->save();
    }

    $poll->delete();
}
```